# Why use parent.$createElement in the vue-router source code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

/src/components/view.js

As the comment writes, can resolve named slots
But what I don't understand is why parent.$createElement different from _

[image]

Comment: The comment says how it differs. h from a parent supposedly owns a different context that allows to access slots. Can't confirm if it's true. Did you try to change h to another one and see what happens with slots?

Comment: I tested using $createElement or _ makes no difference to named slots.
The only difference is that the context property of the rendered component is different.